# How to get last inserted rows in MySQL from different tables?

Tags: mysql

I have a lot of different tables in my database, and I need somehow to get last inserted rows from those tables. Like social networks feeds. Also, those tables are have not random, but unknown names, because they all generated by users.

In example:
I have tables: A,B,C and D with 5k rows in each table.
I need somehow to get last rows from those tables and make it ordered by `id`, like we do in a simple query: `"SELECT * FROM table A ORDER BY id DESC"`, but I'm looking for something like: `"SELECT * FROM A,B,C,D ORDER BY id DESC"`.

**Tables have same structure.**

Comment: _tables have unknown names.._ ? huh? seems your approach is wrong

Comment: @B001ᛦ Yes, they have unknown names for me right now, because they are dynamically created over time. I'm sure there is a way to select all currently created tables and put them in an array.

Comment: It is not good for you to not know the table names, because then you either won't be able to find them, or you'll have to resort to something like dynamic SQL to get fishing for them.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Maybe I can "scan" the database to get their names and put them in an array?

Comment: You can get table names from information_schema.tables

Comment: Tables generated by users, you are either really confident on those users or pretty lucky and have better users than I have.

Comment: BTW you could query the user tables `select TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` prior doing a select to those tables. Im more a sql server guy, so do not know if there is sp_executeSQL equivalent in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use union and order by if your tables have the same structure. Something like:

```
select *
from (
    select * from A
    union all
    select * from B    
    union all
    select * from C
) order by id desc
```

If the tables don't have the same structure then you cannot select * from all and order them and you might want to do two queries. First would be:

```
select id, tableName
    from (
        select id, 'tableA' as tableName from A
        union all
        select id, 'tableB' as tableName from B    
        union all
        select id, 'tableC' as tableName from C
    ) order by id desc
```

Which will give you the last IDs and the tables where they are inserted. And then you need to get the rows from each respective table.

With pure Mysql it will be a bit hard. You can select the table names like:

`SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables;` but still how to use them in the statement? You will need to generate it dynamically

A procedure to generate the query dynamically can be something like ( I haven't tested it but I believe with some debugging it should work) :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE buildQuery (OUT v_query VARCHAR)
BEGIN

 DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE v_table_count INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE v_table varchar(100) DEFAULT "";

 -- declare cursor for tables (this is for all tables but can be changed)

 DEClARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables;

 -- declare NOT FOUND handler
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

 OPEN table_cursor;

 SET v_query="select * from ( ";

 get_table: LOOP

 FETCH table_cursor INTO v_table;
 SET v_table_count = v_table_count + 1;

 IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
 LEAVE get_table;
 END IF;

 if v_table_count>1 THEN
    CONCAT(vquery, " UNION ALL ")
 END IF;

 SET v_query = CONCAT(vquery," select * from ", v_table );

 END LOOP get_table;

 SET v_query = CONCAT(vquery," ) order by id desc " );

 -- here v_query should be the created query with UNION_ALL

 CLOSE table_cursor;

 SELECT @v_query;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: yeah but he will get them somehow right? Dynamically or whatever... if they are unknown forever he won't be able to select from them in the first place right :)

Comment: @VeselinDavidov Thanks you, I think this is what I'm looking for. Now I have to get tables names and pass them to the query somehow.

Comment: @VeselinDavidov Maybe it's better to create a table `E` and insert data to `E` table while I'm inserting data to `A` or `B` or `C` and so on?

Comment: With pure SQL I don't know if that's possible. Probably some kind of procedure or write a program in a language of choice

Comment: I added an example stored procedure to build that query dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If each table's id is counted seperatly you can't order by ID, so you'll need to calculate a global id and use it on all of your tables.

You can do it as follows:

Assuming you have 2 tables A,B:

```
Create Table A(id int NOT NULL auto_increment, name varchar(max), value varchar(max), PRIMARY_KEY(id));
Create Table B(id int NOT NULL auto_increment, name varchar(max), value varchar(max), PRIMARY_KEY(id));
```

Add another table IDS with id as auto increment primary key.

```
Create table IDS (id  int NOT NULL auto_increment, ts Timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY_KEY(id));
```

For all your tables id column should use now the id from the IDS table as foreign key instead of auto increment.

```
Create Table A(id int NOT NULL auto_increment, name varchar(max), value varchar(max), PRIMARY_KEY(id),CONSTRAINT fk_A_id FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCE IDS(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
Create Table B(id int NOT NULL auto_increment, name varchar(max), value varchar(max), PRIMARY_KEY(id),CONSTRAINT fk_A_id FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCE IDS(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

for each table add before insert trigger, the trigger should first insert row to the IDS table and insert the `LAST_INSERT_ID` the table.

```
Create TRIGGER befor_insert_A BEFORE INSERT On A 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  insert into IDS() values ();
  set new.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END

Create TRIGGER befor_insert_B BEFORE INSERT On B 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  insert into IDS() values ();
  set new.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

Now you can create view from all tables with union all, the rows of v can be sorted now by the id and give the cronlogic order of insertion.

```
Create view V AS select * from A UNION ALL select * from B
```

For example you can query on V the latest 10 ids:

```
select * from V Order by id desc LIMIT 10
```

---

Other option is to add timestamp for each table and sort the view by the timestamp.

Answer (score -1):

Hi are you looking for this? However the id is not a good column to see the last updated among different tables.

```
   select *
    from A
    join B
    on 1=1
    join C
    on 1=1
    join D
    on 1=1
    order by A.id desc
```

Comment: yeah but it will order only based on first column ID